# Is it possible to have an SSL site that does not use https?

Tags: http, sharepoint, ssl

I recently developed a site that depends on http referrer tracking (no other choice).  The idea was that the client would post something on their sharepoint site and it would link to the new site - we would check the referrer and use that as authentication to see the page.

Not a great strategy, but the best available at the time - if the referrer did not match we would deny access.

The client's intranet does not use the https prefix, nor a standard top level domain - I know that web browsers do not send referrer information when coming from https to http sites - it is possible that the Sharepoint site does in fact use SSL even though it does not use the https prefix?

Comment: ssl is a protocol. you can send anything you want through an SSL connection. it doesn't HAVE to be http. That being said, a browser will NOT use ssl unless it's an `http(S)` url. if it's saying `http`, then it's NOT encrypted and NOT using ssl.

Comment: +1 for the interesting q. even though its a head-slap of a requirement you're wrestling with there!

Comment: It is the mystery - hopefully I should know more in a week or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hypertext Transfer Protocol Secure (HTTPS) is a widely used communications protocol for secure communication over a computer network, with especially wide deployment on the Internet.

Technically, it is not a protocol in itself; rather, it is the result of simply layering the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) on top of the SSL/TLS protocol, thus adding the security capabilities of SSL/TLS to standard HTTP communications.

If you want to have SSL then URLs will be starting with HTTPS:// so the short answer is: No, not possible.